# sbt run works fine but running jar fails

Tags: java, scala, sbt, akka, akka-http

While I am running from sbt

> (*sbt run*)

my akka http service is running fine, however gives the below error on running using jar

> (*java -jar myservice.jar*)

created by publishLocal

> (*sbt publishLocal*)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.rogers.profileauthn.StartProfileAuthService.<clinit>(StartProfileAuthService.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Dependencies in sbt file are below

```
val akkaVersion = "2.5.11"
val akkaHttpVersion = "10.0.11"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http"            % akkaHttpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream"          % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-jackson"    % akkaHttpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % akkaHttpVersion % Test,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaVersion % Test,
  "junit"              % "junit"             % "4.12"          % Test,
  "com.novocode"       % "junit-interface"   % "0.10"          % Test,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.9",
  "com.github.swagger-akka-http" %% "swagger-akka-http" % "0.11.0",
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "4.1.0",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "18.0",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.11.0"

)
```

and the logger I am using is below

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartService.class);
    LOGGER.info("**** StartService.createAndStartActorSystem Starts ****");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think thats because the jar did not come packaged with your dependency. Can you try creating a fat jar with sbt assembly? https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly. The publishLocal command is used for deploying to an ivy repository and not create jars to run like that i believe. (add plugin and run sbt assembly)